# Is there a plugin to import places of interest (restaurants, hotels, parks, etc.) into QGIS from Google Maps?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, google-maps

I am developing a workflow to identify important/interesting locations contained within a pre-defined area. I would like to know if anyone can indicate a plugin or method to import locations from Google Maps that I can identify if they are contained within my AOI.

Comment: There is one for OpenStreetMap (the QuickOSM plugin), the licencing to get/re-use the data will be simpler than with GoogleMap.

Comment: No this breaks the terms of Google Map API/Places. For this would recommend OpenStreetMap for your Area of Interest. There is plenty of data http://download.geofabrik.de/index.html